# TypeError: sort_values() got an unexpected keyword argument 'by'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, pandas-groupby

I grouped a CSV file by using country and solving the mean of a particular column. I want to sort the new computed mean values in a descending order to plot a bar chart but I am getting the error `TypeError: sort_values() got an unexpected keyword argument 'by'`. The code is as follows:

```
f2 = pd.read_csv('ramen-ratings.csv')
print(f2.dtypes)
gd = (pd.to_numeric(f2['Stars'], errors = 'coerce'). groupby(f2['Country']))
gdm = gd.mean()
print(gdm)
gd_sorted = gdm.sort_values(by = 'Country', ascending = 'False')
plt.figure(figsize = (12,8))
plt.bar(gd_sorted['Stars'].index.values, 'Stars', data = gd_sorted)
plt.show()
```

The error is provided:

```
Review #     int64
Brand       object
Variety     object
Style       object
Country     object
Stars       object
Top Ten     object
```

dtype: object

```
Country

Australia        3.138636
Bangladesh       3.714286
Brazil           4.350000
Cambodia         4.200000
Canada           2.243902
China            3.421893
Colombia         3.291667
Dubai            3.583333
Estonia          3.500000
Fiji             3.875000
Finland          3.583333
Germany          3.638889
Ghana            3.500000
Holland          3.562500
Hong Kong        3.801825
Hungary          3.611111
India            3.395161
Indonesia        4.067460
Japan            3.981605
Malaysia         4.154194
Mexico           3.730000
Myanmar          3.946429
Nepal            3.553571
Netherlands      2.483333
Nigeria          1.500000
Pakistan         3.000000
Philippines      3.329787
Poland           3.625000
Sarawak          4.333333
Singapore        4.126147
South Korea      3.790554
Sweden           3.250000
Taiwan           3.665402
Thailand         3.384817
UK               2.997101
USA              3.457043
United States    3.750000
Vietnam          3.187963
Name: Stars, dtype: float64
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-107-ce508bbadecd> in <module>
      5 gdm = gd.mean()
      6 print(gdm)
----> 7 gd_sorted = gdm.sort_values(by = 'Country', ascending = 'False')
      8 plt.figure(figsize = (12,8))
      9 plt.bar(gd_sorted['Stars'].index.values, 'Stars', data = gd_sorted)

TypeError: sort_values() got an unexpected keyword argument 'by'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the documentation?  `by` is a positional parameter, not a keyword.  Also, boolean values in Python are not strings.  Ironically, the string 'False' is a True value.

You need:

```
gd_sorted = gdm.sort_values('Country', ascending=False)
```

Comment: Yes, I think the error is coming from ‘gdm’ because  ‘Stars’ is no longer a parameter in ‘gdm’. I think it can’t find ‘Stars’ because it’s no longer there. How can I make ‘Stars’ a parameter in gdm?

Comment: No, it definitely is not.  I told you EXACTLY what the problems are, and for that matter so did the error message.  Just remove the `by=` from that call.  The `by` parameter is positional, not keyword.

Comment: You right, Thanks. My bad